# Putting a sub panel for a home office/bedroom?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, generator

Recently, our neighborhood had a power outage for a few days. Causing my office/bedroom to lose power completely which was a bit of an inconvenience.

Out of curiosity, I began googling about integrating a portable generator into a home. By creating an inlet and integrating it into your circuit panel, you could have it power your home without having a mess of extension cords everywhere.

Now my current electrical panel is a mess, and something I would not want to touch/nor get into. I have done some wiring inside my home to add a few receptacles, so I am not completely clueless to working with electrical. I was curious if I could reroute all the wiring for my office/bedroom into a sub panel that would connect to my main circuit breaker panel however with a inlet ran to this sub panel so that in the event of a power outage, I can power this one room.

I am not very knowledgeable of electrical codes, and am pretty overwhelmed by them honestly.

For better understanding, I drew up a little diagram.
[image: Diagram of sub panel idea]

Comment: The basic answer is: Yes, this will work, with a *transfer switch* so that the generator power can't interfere with utility power. The long answer is: Harper or ThreePhaseEel or one of the other pros will give you all the details. But the basic concept is valid.

Comment: Shoot us a photo of your existing main panel so we can see what we're working with.

Comment: As well as a transfer switch, you need a way to ensure the generator+office is properly earthed when it has been isolated from the utility power.  Also, where in the world are you?  Electrical codes can vary quite widely.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Are there other loads (like the fridge, miscellaneous lights, and such) that you'd want to run on the generator? Also, can you provide us with photos of the existing panel, and how large is your generator, or are you planning to acquire one for this?

Comment: I am in New York(U.S), Long Island to be exact. 

Load would consist of: Mac Pro 5,1(mainly), 2 monitors, a few chargers for an iPhone, iPad,etc, 2 Philip Hue lights, and a refrigerator. 

We own a PowerStroke 6000w generator currently. I will post pictures as soon as possible!

Comment: City water? If you are on city water that generator will be plenty large enough.

Comment: What is your plan for keeping that generator in fuel? Do you own a Macbook?

Comment: Does your network source (DSL modem,  fiber box, etc.) need power too?

Comment: What do you have for an HVAC system?

Comment: Also, yes, are you on city or well water @JonCiccone?